# How to connect to a websocket that requires client-certificate using Python

Tags: python, websocket, client-certificates

I'm using Python's [websockets](https://github.com/aaugustin/websockets) to connect to a websocket server using basic-authentication.
The server now requires me to present a ssl/tls client certificate which I have in a P12 format.

How do I configure my websockets client to use the certficiate found in the P12 file?

Answer (score 2):

First thing I had to extract the certificate and keys from the `P12` file.
Assume my client-certificate is stored in P12 format in a file called `cert.p12`, I use openssl to extract the certificate and keys (openssl will prompt for the certificate's password):

```sh
    openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -out cert.pem -clcerts -nokeys
    openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -out cert.keys -nocerts
```

Now, in Python:

```py
import asyncio
import pathlib
import ssl

import websockets

username = "..."
password = "..."
host = "..."
url = f"wss://{username}:{password}@{host}/..."


ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
ssl_context.load_default_certs()
ssl_context.load_cert_chain(
    pathlib.Path("cert.pem"),
    pathlib.Path("cert.keys"),
    "..."  # The certificate's password goes here
)


async def consume():
    try:
        async with websockets.connect(uri=url, ssl=ssl_context) as websocket:
            async for message in websocket:
                print(message)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(consume())


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```